# Sort Table by specific variable before export to xtable

Tags: r, latex

From a large dataset of survey responses I have to construct tables sorted by decreasing values of a specific variable. For example, here is one table I created:

```
t8  <- xtabs(meanq8 ~ respondent, data = bfk1)
t13 <- xtabs(meanq13 ~ respondent, data=bfk1)
t18 <- xtabs(meanq18 ~ respondent, data=bfk1)
t23 <- xtabs(meanq23 ~ respondent, data=bfk1)
t28 <- xtabs(meanq28 ~ respondent, data=bfk1)
t33 <- xtabs(meanq33 ~ respondent, data=bfk1)

tab.L6 <- rbind(t8, t13, t18, t23, t28, t33) 
rownames(tab.L6) <- c("I give teachers a sense of overall purpose", "I help clarify the specific meaning of the school's mission in terms of its practical implications for programs and instruction", "I communicate the school mission to staff and students", "I encourage the development of school norms supporting openness to change", "I help teachers understand the relationship between our school's mission and District initiatives", "I work toward whole-staff consensus in establishing priorities for school goals")
```

This results in a 6x4 double matrix with column names of You, Your.Staff, All.Principals, All.Staff. Now, before I run xtable I need to sort tab.L6 by descending values of Your.Staff.

I tried to work with plyr and data.table as well as the base sort and order functions. If I execute the following

```
tL6 <- as.data.frame(tab.L6)
table.L6 <- arrange(tL6, desc(Your.Staff))
```

I end up with the desired sort but missing rownames.

```
  You Your.Staff All.Principals All.Staff
1   5        5.0            3.8       3.8
2   5        4.5            4.0       3.9
3   5        4.5            3.8       3.6
4   5        4.0            3.5       3.7
5   5        4.0            3.6       3.9
6   4        4.0            3.4       3.7
```

Is there a way to sort and retain rownames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about indexing your rownames and adding them post sort?

```
tab.L6 = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(24,1,100),6))
rownames(tab.L6) <- c("I give teachers...", "I help clarify...", "I communicate..", "I encourage...", "I help teachers...", "I work toward...")
names(tab.L6) = c('You','Your.Staff','All.Principals','All.Staff')
tab.L6$index = 1:6
tab.L6

vecnames = c("I give teachers...", "I help clarify...", "I communicate..", "I encourage...", "I help teachers...", "I work toward...")

(t2 = arrange(tab.L6, desc(Your.Staff)))
rownames(t2) = vecnames[t2$index]
t2
```

output:

```
                         You Your.Staff All.Principals All.Staff index
I help teachers... 33.620593  94.174583       12.93681  60.34864     5
I work toward...   98.250119  84.166085       79.57018  89.76993     6
I help clarify...  85.478336  52.664455       71.82487  18.08677     2
I encourage...     55.972257  50.095689       55.96154  60.04199     4
I give teachers... 20.183314  28.812243       21.71087  29.02465     1
I communicate..     8.520616   3.409428       75.94298  56.98706     3
```

and you can then delete the index column prior to exporting the table:

```
t2$index = NULL
```